# Rollbacks show the wrong revision ID when linked to directly

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, rollbacks

Looking at the revision history of [this post](https://meta.superuser.com/posts/4383/revisions), the rollback IDs, i.e. the edit summaries, are correctly shown:

> [image]

However, on [the individual revision](https://meta.superuser.com/revisions/4383/8) (here, number 8), the edit text is off and shows what's probably the unique identifier of the revision:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be pushed out in the next build (> rev 2012.2.15.1080).